# Oracle Stored Procedure compilation error

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I'm new to PL/SQL. Can anyone please help fix my compilation error? Your help is much appreciated. Also, after I would like to call this procedure to check and add a new user.

```
create or replace procedure CheckAddUser ( userid in varchar2(20))
as
declare vartmp number;
begin
    SELECT nvl((SELECT distinct 1 FROM crm_admin.LTY_USER_STORE WHERE usr_nm = userid  ), 0) INTO :varTmp FROM dual;    
    IF (:varTmp = 0) THEN
       dbms_output.put_line('the user ' || ':userid' || ' does not exist');

    elsif (:varTmp = 1) THEN
       dbms_output.put_line('the user ' || ':userid' || '  already exist');
    End if;
end;
```

Comment: What is the compilation error you are seeing?

Comment: @Chetan  in sqldeveloper, I got a couple of: 1. Error(2,44): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     := . ) , @ % default character The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.   2. Error(4,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior external language The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
create or replace procedure checkadduser(userid in varchar2)
as
    vartmp number;
begin
    select coalesce(max(1), 0) into vartmp
    from dual
    where exists (
            select 1
            from crm_admin.lty_user_store
            where usr_nm = userid
            );
    if vartmp = 0 then
        dbms_output.put_line('the user ' || userid || ' does not exist');
    elsif vartmp = 1 then
       dbms_output.put_line('the user ' || userid || '  already exist');
    end if;
end;
/
```

Changes made:

1. Removed the size from parameter
2. Removed the `declare` keyword - not part of the procedure syntax
3. Modified the query to stop searching as soon as a row is found and return 1 otherwise 0.

   ```
   select coalesce(max(1), 0) into varTmp
   from dual
   where exists (
           select 1
           from crm_admin.lty_user_store
           where usr_nm = userid
           );
   ```

   If the usr_nm is unique in your table, this will work well too (this *can* be used even if it's not unique but can be bit less performant if number of rows per usr_nm can be arbitrarily large):

   ```
   select coalesce(max(1), 0)
   into varTmp
   from crm_admin.lty_user_store
   where usr_nm = userid
   ```
4. Do not use `:` with the variables and parameters.

Comment: @ GurV     now it's working. Thank you for your help! begin
  2  checkadduser('MikeC');
  3  end;
  4  /
the user MikeC  already exist

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **":"** with var. 
I did some changes, which I would migth use:

```
--I recommended to change procedure to function, then you can use it in SQL
create or replace 
procedure CheckAddUser ( userid in varchar2)
as
  --Best practics, use self-describing variables
    isuserexist number(1,0); -- vartmp
    message_suff varchar2(30):=' does not exist';
begin
  --Best practics, first check the parameters
  if trim(userid) is null then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Param userid is empty');
  end if;

    select count(*) into isuserexist
  from crm_admin.lty_user_store 
  where usr_nm = userid;

  --only one if, reads easier
  if isUserExist > 0 then
    message_suff:= ' already exist';
  end if;

  dbms_output.put_line('the user ' || ':userid' || message_suff);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and tips of good practices. It helps! @Farkhat

Comment: `trim(userid)=''` will never be true. Also if we're talking best practice, we can avoid unnecessary brackets around `if` conditions and `count(*)` is the standard expression for counting rows, not `count(1)` (plus it's less to type).